# Python - GUI, работа с интерфейсом и сторонними программами

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие модули нужно подключать, чтобы запускать программу (например, игру) и взаимодействовать с ней?
Затем уже в самой программе находить поля для ввода данных (например, для входа в учётную запись) и автоматически заполнять данные поля.

Т.е. нужны модули для запуска программы, для поиска поля ввода в ней и для заполнения данного поля буквами и цифрами.
По сути, нужны какие-то модули для взаимодействия с приложениями или сторонними интерфейсами.

Comment: К примеру PyQT...

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке есть модуль `tkinter`

Comment: Похоже, вам может пригодиться `pyautogui`. Игрался как-то с этим модулем, вот пример запуска и работы с калькулятором винды: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/51fecb7117f29bd26bdc6449a78872f9343bca27/pyautogui__keyboard__examples/win_calc_clicker

Comment: Мне кажется pyautogui не подходит т.к. это просто управление мышкой и клавиатурой. Мне бы узнать точный метод для поиска поля ввода не при помощи курсора мыши, а чтобы как то командой система его . Т.е. когда входишь в игру там есть 2 поля для ввода данных(логин пароль - не вэб игра), если к примеру установить оконный режим и сместить окно в сторону, то придется постоянно менять координаты курсора. Может ли в данной ситуации помочь модуль pywinauto? Или всё же единственный вариант pyautogui ?